# Task Schedule Job withChain Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, queue

I need to run a series of Jobs that run in sequence in Laravel at a scheduled interval (weekly) The [withChain](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#job-chaining) method works perfectly for this:

```
firstJob::withChain([
    new secondJob,
    new thirdJob
 ]);
```

When trying to run the chain within the [Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling):

```
$schedule->job(firstJob::withChain([
    new secondJob,
    new thirdJob
 ]))->weekly();
```

I get the following error:

```
 In BoundMethod.php line 135:

 Method Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch::handle() does not exist
```

The output I get from the Scheduler in the cli is:

```
Running scheduled command: Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch
```

So I understand that the job method isn't actually calling the job but the dispatch() method in the Dispatchable trait.

My question is how can I run chained Jobs within the Laravel Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by replacing $schedule->job() with $schedule->call(). The closure simple runs the job::withChain(). I now have a supervisord command making sure the queue:work artisan command is running in the background so the scheduler is responsible for firing the job queue on the allocated time which triggers the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$schedule->call()` looses the ability to specify a queue name, and other job specific parameters.

To retain this, you should use the schedule job command, which can be chained as follows:

```
$schedule->job((new firstJob())->chain([
    new secondJob(),
    new thirdJob()
]), 'queue-name')->everyFiveMinutes();
```

Comment: ```  
 $schedule->job((new \App\Jobs\FetchEmailAttachment)->chain([
            new \App\Jobs\SplitAttachment,
            new \App\Jobs\ResendAttachment
        ]), 'mailbox')->everyMinute();
```
I am trying to execute same process but it only executing first job ignoring others

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but may help other people:

```php
$schedule->call(function () {
    firstJob::withChain([
        new secondJob,
        new thirdJob
    ])->dispatch()->allOnQueue('queue_name');
})->weekly();
```